# Regular expression to check if number is greater than 1

Tags: java, validation, dojo

Could someone help me to generate a regular expression for checking if entered number is greater than 1. This is what I tried:'[1-9][0-9]|[2-9]' but this does not allow me to enter more than 2-digits. I very new into this.Please help me..

Comment: Sure, it can be done with regex - but why?

Comment: [0-9] <wildcard for variable amout of times>[2-9]
That should do it, but I agree with amit, this is not something you should do using regex.

Comment: Its actually for validation of fields using dojo, where I require this regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the following regular expression: `[2-9]|([1-9][0-9]+)`

This means: a single digit between 2 and 9, or: a digit between 1 and 9 followed by one or more digits.

Regular expressions are very powerful, and sometimes people try to use them for everything. This is typically an example of where you don't really need a regular expression. Just checking `if (n > 1)` is simpler and more clear than using a regular expression for this task.

Comment: this will allow `00`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj You are right, fixed. It shows why `if (n > 1)` would have been much simpler and less error prone...

Answer (score 1):

You can go for something like:

```
regex = "([2-9][0-9]*|1[0-9]+)"
```

Code :

```
    String regex = "([2-9][0-9]*|1[0-9]+)";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher("");

    m.reset("1");
    System.out.println(m.matches());
    m.reset("2");
    System.out.println(m.matches());
    m.reset("10");
    System.out.println(m.matches());
    m.reset("24");
    System.out.println(m.matches());
    m.reset("10842");
    System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Explanation:

You basically have two choices

1. the number can  start with 2,3,...,9 - and have any number of digits
   after it, of any kind: `[2-9][0-9]*`
2. The number can start with 1, and MUST have some following digit: `1[0-9]+`

Combining them gets you the regex.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thank you, mistyped it in the code. (The explanation does explain it however, thanks for your feedback).

Answer (score 1):

This will allow the number only if it's greater than 1.

```
"^(?:[1-9]\\d+|[2-9])$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oH2sW9/2)

Answer (score 0):

Either the last digit has to be greater than `1` or a non-`0` digit has to occur as digit other than the last one. The regex for this is:

```
"[2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one looks straightforward:

```
^0*[1-9]\d*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/copLvd/2)